# Foreign Key Android Not Working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

```
categories(id, name, slug);
places(id, name, cat_id(foreignKey));
```

When I query the table using

```
String where = "cat_id = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"1488764085"}; 
c = db.query("places", new String[]{"name", "cat_id"}, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

The returned Cursor is having items but when I append another field in the where clause like below the Cursor returns the count -1

```
String where = "name = ? AND cat_id = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"xxx", "1488764085"}; 
c = db.query("places", new String[]{"name", "cat_id"}, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
```

Can any one point out the actual issue why it is happening so

**Note : The place table is having a field with value "xxx".**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed and posting this so that it might help some one else.

By adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the foreign key actually solved my issue.

```
foreign key cat_id references categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```